# How to store curly brackets in a Bash variable

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

I am trying to write a bash script. I am not sure why in my script:

```
ls {*.xml,*.txt}
```

works okay, but

```
name="{*.xml,*.txt}"
ls $name
```

doesn't work. I get

```
ls: cannot access {*.xml,*.txt}: No such file or directory
```

Comment: [What are you trying to accomplish?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: `{*.xml,*.txt}` just expands to `*.xml *.txt`, which expands to the file names matching those patterns, so the first command is just the same as `ls *.xml *.txt`, which really begs the question of what you actually wish to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression

```
ls {*.xml,*.txt}
```

results in [Brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) and shell passes the expansion (if any) to `ls` as arguments.  Setting `shopt -s nullglob` makes this expression evaluate to nothing when there are no matching files.

Double quoting the string suppresses the expansion and shell stores the literal contents in your variable `name` (not sure if that is what you wanted).  When you invoke `ls` with `$name` as the argument, shell does the variable expansion but no brace expansion is done.

As @Cyrus has mentioned, `eval ls $name` will force brace expansion and you get the same result as that of `ls {\*.xml,\*.txt}`.

Comment: in addition: Not only the double quoting but also the variable assignment doesn't support brace expansion. There is no difference between `name="{\*.xml,*.txt}"` and `name={\*.xml,*.txt}` in this case. Expansions (if supported and enabled) are done when reading the command line.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to add that point but didn't see it being mentioned in the Bash manual.

Comment: [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead)

Comment: Brace expansion results in multiple words, so it cannot sensibly work in an assignment. The expansions done on assignments [are listed in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameters.html#index-shell-variable).

Answer (score 1):

The reason your expansion doesn't work is that brace expansion is performed *before* variable expansion, see [Shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions) in the manual.

I'm not sure what it is you're trying to do, but if you want to store a list of file names, use an array:

```
files=( {*.txt,*.xml} )           # these two are the same
files=(*.txt *.xml)
ls -l "${files[@]}"               # give them to a command
for file in "${files[@]}" ; do    # or loop over them
    dosomething "$file"
done
```

`"${array[@]}"` expands to all elements of the array, as separate words. (*remember the quotes!*)