# Wildcard expands in shell but not in script

Tags: bash

So when I want to use bash to list out files starting with multiple letters I can do something like `echo /home/username/{A,B,C}*` which correctly echoes the filenames starting with `A`, `B`, `C`.

I'm trying to do the same with a bash variable with user input inside a script, say something along the lines of(say the script name is `run_user_input.sh`):
    `var=$1;echo $var;`

And I run it as `./run_user_input.sh "/home/username/{A,B}*"`.

But this just echoes `/home/username/{A,B}*`.

Note that `var="/home/username/A*";echo $var;` still works correctly.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In double quotes, only a few things are expanded: parameter and command substitution, most importantly, but no filenames (and no brace expansion), so `*` within double quotes is always literal.

Then, on the right-hand side of an assignment, there is *also* no filename and brace expansion, so `var=*` will put a literal `*` into `var`, even without quotes. Your last example "works" only because you don't quote the expansion of `$var`, but it contains literally `/home/username/A*`.

The way to do it is to use an array:

```
fnames=(/home/username/{A,B,C}*)
```

This will perform both brace and filename expansion, and the array elements will contain one filename each, properly escaping spaces and glob characters. Access them with proper quoting:

```
echo "${fnames[0]}"
```

gives you the first filename, for example.

If you supply the pattern as a parameter to a script, there's probably no way around using `eval`:

```
pattern=$1
eval fnames=("$pattern")
```

***This comes with the [usual warnings](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) about `eval`***. If you supply as a pattern the following:

```
pattern='x); echo pwnd #'
```

`eval` will expand the line to

```
fnames=(x); echo pwnd #)
```

and actually run the injected command, which could be less friendly than just an echo.

Sadly, the robust method

```
eval "$(printf 'fnames=(%q)' "$pattern")"
```

doesn't work, as it prevents expansion.

To avoid this, I'd recommend rewriting your script to take multiple arguments and let the shell do the expansion:

```
./yourscript path/to/dir/{A,B}*
```

and in the script something like

```
for file; do <something>; done
```

(which is the same as `for file in "$@"; do <something>; done`). Now you have the benefits of expansion being taken care of by the shell, without the drawbacks of `eval`.

Comment: Worth noting that brace expansion is *not* performed on the result of a parameter expansion, and `bash` is exhibiting its default behavior of treating a non-matching pattern (non-matching here because of the unexpanded braces) as a literal string.

Comment: The thing is that my script takes `"/home/username/{A,B,C}*"` as customizable user input. So it worked as `echo $1` where `$1 == "/home/username/{A,B,C}*"` - I should have stated this more clearly. The above solution wont work directly with such an input right?

Comment: @tangy Something like in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43751540/how-to-store-curly-brackets-in-a-bash-variable

Comment: @tangy You need to update the question with *exactly* how your script receives that input.

Comment: @tangy You're likely to end up with needing `eval` if you want to evaluate user input that contains brace expansions.

Comment: Thanks, yes I've updated the question. And yes something like the question you have linked.

Comment: @tangy I've updated the answer, but see remark at the end.

Comment: Thanks for both the answer and the additional suggestion avoiding eval!